# Conways Game of Life not updating

Tags: java

I have created my own Conway's Game of Life in Java and it seems that I can get the program to output the first "life" but it will not update through 3 iterations, it will just print out the first life 3 times. I have tried rewriting my `copyLife()` and `runTheLife()` methods but nothing seemed to work. My question is why won't my "lifes" update through 3 times.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Life {

        private static final int ROW = 20; 
        private static final int COL = 20; 

public static void main(String[] args) {


        // sets up a 20x20 array with a 2 row x column. adds 2 for remaining edges so no overflow in array.

         boolean[][] nextLife = new boolean[ROW+2][COL+2]; 
         boolean[][] currLife = new boolean[ROW+2][COL+2]; 


         //sets whole life equal to false
        for(int i = 1; i <= currLife.length - 1; i++) 
        {

           for(int j = 1; j <= currLife.length - 1; j++) 
           {
            currLife[i][j] = false;
            nextLife[i][j] = false;
           }
        }

         //  life game
        for (int i = 1; i < currLife.length - 1; i++) 
        {
             for (int j = 1; j < currLife.length - 1; j++) 
                 {

                    currLife[8][8]= true;
                    currLife[9][9]=true;
                    currLife[9][10] = true;
                    currLife[10][9] = true;
                    currLife[10][10] = true;

                  }

        }

        runTheLife(currLife, nextLife); 
}

private static void runTheLife (boolean[][] currLife, boolean[][] nextLife) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {

        copyLife(currLife, nextLife);
        runThroughRules(currLife, nextLife);
        printLife(nextLife);
        System.out.println();
        copyLife(nextLife, currLife);
        runThroughRules(currLife, nextLife);
        printLife(nextLife);

        }

}
private static int countLiveNeighbors(int row, int col, boolean[][] currLife)
{
      //counts all the live neighbors around a specific cell (checks every cell)        
    int count = 0;
    if(currLife[row-1][col]){
        count++;
    }
    if(currLife[row+1][col]){
        count++;
    }
    if(currLife[row][col-1]){
        count++;
    }
    if(currLife[row][col+1]){
        count++;
    }
    if(currLife[row-1][col-1]){
        count++;
    }
    if(currLife[row-1][col+1]){
        count++;
    }
    if(currLife[row+1][col-1]){
        count++;
    }
    if(currLife[row+1][col+1]){
        count++;
    }
 return count;
 }

private static void runThroughRules(boolean[][] currLife, boolean[][] nextLife)
{
      //determines if the surrounding cells, and the cell itself lives or dies for each iteration         
    for (int i = 1; i < currLife.length - 1; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 1; j < currLife.length - 1; j++) 
        {
            if(countLiveNeighbors(i, j, currLife) == 3)
               nextLife[i][j] = true;
            if(countLiveNeighbors(i, j, currLife) < 2)
               nextLife[i][j] = false;
            if(countLiveNeighbors(i, j, currLife) > 3)
               nextLife[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
 }

private static void copyLife(boolean[][] currLife, boolean[][]nextLife) 
{
     //copies all the nextLife values to the currLife values        
    for (int i = 1; i < currLife.length - 1; i++) 
    {

        for (int j = 1; j < currLife.length - 1; j++) 
        {
            nextLife[i][j] = currLife[i][j];


        }
    }
}


private static void printLife(boolean[][] nextLife) 
{
     //prints out the program, o being a living cell, a space being a dead cell        
    for (int i = 1; i <= ROW; i++) 
    {

        for (int j = 1; j <= COL; j++) 
        {
            if (nextLife[i][j])
            {
                System.out.print("1");
            } else {
                System.out.print("0");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
     //shows when the changes ends and begins
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

My output currently is below with '1' being alive cells and '0' being dead cells. I get this same output 3 times without the rules of the game updating each "life" it passes.

```
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000100000000000
00000001010000000000
00000000110000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
```

Comment: Hi, what you want into output ?

Comment: the updated "life" after each passing through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different initial configuration of live / dead cells.

Your initial configuration is like so . . .

```
00000
01000
00110
00110
00000
```

After the first generation, you get the following

```
00000
00100
01010
00110
00000
```

This can be considered a locked scenario. No dead cell has three live neighbors so all dead cells will remain dead. Similarly all live cells have two or three live neighbors so all live cells will remain alive. So since there are no changes to cells, you'll see the same output for every generation after the first generation.